# How to train a model to detect an event in a time line sequence of data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a time line of a users data and i want to train a model to detect events.

For example an event could be a gesture in a time line of accelerometer data.

or

time line of looking at the time (looking at a watch), (labeling nerves or calm).

What machine learning algorithm  will be appropriate for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This task is known as **Event Detection** and can be performed using Natural Language Processing (NLP) techniques.

There is no 'appropriate' or 'not appropriate' algorithm. You have to extract various features (e.g. Part-of-Speech tags) that enable the algorithm(s) to detect events. Then, you need to evaluate the implemented algorithms/models (assuming that you have also tuned the corresponding parameters for each algorithm) and decide which one is the best (in terms of performance). Also, you need to decide which features are helpful and which are not.

**These papers might be a good starting point:**

[Machine Learning Algorithms for Event Detection](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10994-010-5184-9.pdf)

[Event Detection Challenges, Methods, and Applications
in Natural and Artificial Systems](http://www.dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA503477)

Comment: Thanks, i will look in to this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed answer as to what is the best approach. Based on experience, my favourite approach to modelling series generally is LSTM nets. These work great with time events as long as you have enough data. You can either try to look for anomalies. For this you could use an LSTM that triggers when something 'unexpected' happens. Another option would be defining different states (e.g `is.event = {0,1}`) and train your LSTM as a normal classifier (check this [question](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-LSTM-Networks-for-time-series-anomaly-detection) in Quora). You can use for example `keras` to implement this easily in python.

If data in not so abundant, you can also try other nice sequential models like HMM and HSMM. These are also supervised model that learn from sequential data. In the case of HSMM you also take into account the time each state has occur which depending on your data can be of use. As far as I know scikit-learn only supports HMM, however there is a HSMM library available [here](https://github.com/mattjj/pyhsmm).

Finally, some remarks about processing your data. If you intend to do batch learning, any of the models here suggested should work fine. However, if you want to do on-line learning (meaning that you make prediction on the fly as data arrives), you will need to stick to LSTM or perhaps check this alternative if you decide to use any of the Bayesian Approach: [paper on-line hsmm](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7792429/)

Hope this helps!